# ASP.NET Core Error When Sending Ajax List net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In the asp.net core project, I want to send a list to the controller with ajax. It's working when my list size is between 10-15, but when I try to send more than 99, I get the error  `net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

**View:**

```
for.....
var items = {
  ProductId: productId,
  ColorId: colorId,
  ShippigId: shippingId,
  Count: colorCount
}
shippingArray.push(items);

var json = JSON.stringify(shippingArray);
var url = '@Url.Action("XXXX","XXXXX")';
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  traditional: true,
  datatype: "JSON",
  async: true,
  data: {
    "body": json
  },
  success: function () {

  }
});
```

```
(99) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}........ ] vendor.bundle.base.js:2 

GET https://localhost:5001/xxxxx/xxxxx?body=%5B%7B%22ProductId%22%3A%2235%22%2C%22ColorId%22%3A%221%22%2C%22ShippigId%22%3A%22324%22%2ne
t::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

`Controller:`

```
 public async Task<bool> ShippingFinishDeleteItem(String body)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: So, you are getting data like this way `[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}` in controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the asp.net core project, I want to send a list to the controller
> with ajax. It's working when my list size is between 10-15, but when I
> try to send more than 99, I get the error
> net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

**What it is:**

[image]

Well, your error is pretty obvious. As per, [https://www.w3.org/Protocols convension](https://www.w3.org/Protocols) we used to encounter similar error in following scenario

> When the server is refusing to service the request because the Request-URI
> is longer than the server is willing to interpret.

**Explanation:**

From your request, it seems that you are sending request using `GET` method. As you might know depnding on browsers configuration `GET method` can carry data upto `2,048KB`. Reqeust which exceed above limits would cause  `net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` error. You can get [more details here.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/maximum-url-length-is-2-083-characters-in-internet-explorer-174e7c8a-6666-f4e0-6fd6-908b53c12246)

**Solution:**

Before, any concrete solution we ought to have a logical decision that is, if our request length for data would have the possibility to reach browser max limit in those scenario, we should better use `POST Http Verb or Method`  as `POST` method is not limited by the size of the URL for submitting name/value pairs. These pairs are transferred in the header and not in the URL. We can even try `[RequestSizeLimit(500 * 1024 * 1024)]` in asp.net core. However, ideal implementation would be using `POST Method` in case of large data request. [You can get more details here.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/maximum-url-length-is-2-083-characters-in-internet-explorer-174e7c8a-6666-f4e0-6fd6-908b53c12246)

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<bool> ShippingFinishDeleteItem(String body)
        {

            return true;
        }
```

Javascript/Jquery:

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var productId = "Pro:";
            var colorId = "Col:";
            var shippingId = "Shi:";
            var colorCount = "Cnt:";
           
            var shippingArray = [];
            for(let i=0; i<=150;i++){
                var items = {
                    ProductId: productId+i,
                    ColorId: colorId+i,
                    ShippigId: shippingId+i,
                    Count: colorCount+i
                }
                shippingArray.push(items);
            }

            console.log(shippingArray);

            var json = JSON.stringify(shippingArray);
            var url = '@Url.Action("ShippingFinishDeleteItem","MyControllerName")';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                traditional: true,
                datatype: "JSON",
                async: true,
                data: {
                    "body": json
                },
                success: function () {

                }
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: hi, you're awesome my problem is solved. I was doing my transaction with get when I changed it to post I did not have a problem with the sending limit. Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome and glad to assist you on this.